# Reat Native Expo custom fontWeight doesn't work on iOS device

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I loaded the open-sans-regular font according to expo website:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans-regular': require('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')
  })

  this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })
}
```

And when I apply the following style on text, **it works on Android device, but not iOS device**. Did I missing anything or I need to load the 'open-sans-bold' and make use the fontFamily attribute?

```
<Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Testing</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the font, you'll need to install the bold font as well...

```
await Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans-regular': require('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold': require('assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
  })
```

And make sure you're declaring the `fontFamily` in styles

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold', fontSize: 56 }}>
  Hello, world!
</Text>
```

More info, see [Using Custom Fonts in Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts#__next):

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know I can use fontFamily, but the question was can I use the fontWeight attribute to achieve the same goal. It does work on Android device, which the text will become bold when I set the fontWeight to bold, but it doesn't have any effect on iPhone.

Comment: Yes, I would think that should work too, but maybe there's a problem with the 'bold' enum with that specific font. Have you tried a numeric value, say 900?

`enum('normal', 'bold', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900')`

(see docs for [fontWeight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#fontweight))